# get data of mysql database and display on html page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

My Question is simple: which programming language do you recommand me to do what I want below.

I have an html page and some javascript. On the html page you see a card game and some actions of the card. In my javascript I hardcoded for the moment the cards of every players. In the future I don't want hardcoded decks. I want to get the info of which players has which cards in his hand from a mysql database.

I don't think javascript (or jquery) is the way to do it. What do you recommand me to use?

Comment: PHP is typically used for server side scripting on web pages.

Comment: `PHP`. While it is possible to access your database with `javascript` or `jQuery`, it is **NOT** recommended. You can combine the `jQuery` and `PHP` using `ajax`, which will probably do what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Ajax Calls, a MySQL database with phpmyAdmin for example and some php.

Ajax 101: https://gist.github.com/joelrojo/c54765a748cd87a395a2b865359d6add

Answer (score 0):

You can consider nodejs. The package mysql can allow you to insert data into the database and read them when needed.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to retrieve info of which players has which cards in his hand from your MySQL database.

For further reference please refer http://php.net/docs.php